# How to make redmine/default/files High availability?

Tags: redmine, high-availability

Currently i working on task make redmine high availabity using pacemaker and Corosync in new 3 servers. I successfully done part of database synchronization. But redmine saved all files in /var/lib/redmine/default/files/

Now I want to migrate this folder from my old redmine to new redmine. how to synchronize /var/lib/redmine/default/files/ to my new servers.

currently i am doing copy and paste from old redmine to my new servers. i know this is a stupid solution.

anyone know how to synchronize this folder in my 3 servers or how to put this on a network share.

please help me.

**pacemaker status**

```
root@twinkie:~# pcs status
Cluster name: mycluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: server3 (version 1.1.16-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Sep  1 11:47:04 2020
Last change: Mon Aug 31 21:45:25 2020 by root via crm_attribute on server3

3 nodes configured
5 resources configured

Online: [ server1 server2 server3 ]

Full list of resources:

 MasterVip      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server3
 Apache (ocf::heartbeat:apache):        Started server3
 Master/Slave Set: pgsql-ha [pgsqld]
     Masters: [ server3 ]
     Slaves: [ server1 server2 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [DRBD](https://www.linbit.com/drbd/) to synchronize a block device holding the files between your nodes.

Comment: can I mount all redmine folder to DRBD drive ?  I am so confuse with the part of mount. please help